# script.google.com refused to connect. - How to understand and clear this problem

Tags: google-apps-script, connection-refused

I am cross-training myself from Cold Fusion to Google Apps Scripts and am trying to replicate a menu system I had in CF. The code works but I get the above error when I run it. I have seen responses to the accounts.google.com problem but this looks different.

Second attempt at this project, as the replies I got to my previous question made me think and code afresh. Now my code is totally gs code with no html template files. It extracts the necessary data from a google sheet based on the email address of the user. Then it produces an html table for each menu option the user has access to. This works. If I right click a menu link and copy the link, then paste it back into the browser and hit return, it works like that as well. BUT, when I just click on the menu link within the page I get the error. Here is the code I am using. I think it just responds to me so you may need to copy it to have a play. I am expecting the problem to be somewhere else, not in the code. Any ideas?

Code.gs

```
/\*

* * Created by Jukebox

* * 

* * Response handler based on a template example by Rafael Vidal

* * 

\*/

// These are the entry points, just two lines of code to anchor them
// All the rest is run from the handleResponse() function
// It sends the get and post requests to the same function
// Parameters can have the same name in either Get or Post
// A response may need to check that it is Get or Post and throw the other out
// There is no point processing a form if doGet was used (no form!)
// That's all folks

function doGet(e)  {return handleResponse(e,'doGet'); }
function doPost(e) {return handleResponse(e,'doPost'); }
```

responsehandler.gs

```
// This function will fire when a raw page request comes in
//    and also in the case of Get or Post. 
// All calls to the web site are handled here. 
// There are no other html pages in the system, 
//    as all the work is done by functions. 
// The parameter ActionCode is used to control which functions are used. 

function handleResponse(e,fromGetOrPost)
  {
// Firstly extract the elements that will be added to the log
    var thisCurrentUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var thisCallType    = fromGetOrPost;
    var thisActionCode  = e.parameter.actioncode;
  
// Then log them in the spreadsheet for future reference
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(getSheetUrl());
    var sheet       = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('logit');
        sheet.appendRow([thisCurrentUser, new Date(), thisCallType, thisActionCode]);

// Identify the web page location        
    var thisWebAddress  = getHtmlUrl();

// Now build up the html page in modules
    var HTMLString = "<html>";
        HTMLString = "<head><title>My first world</title></head>";
        HTMLString = HTMLString + "<body>";
    var menublock = interogatemenu(thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode,thisWebAddress);
        HTMLString = HTMLString + menublock;
        HTMLString = HTMLString + fwc();
        HTMLString = HTMLString + swc();
        HTMLString = HTMLString + "</body></html>";

        HTMLOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HTMLString);
    return HTMLOutput
  }
```

staticdata.gs

```
// function to return the URL of the spreadsheet
function getSheetUrl()
  {
    var    sheetRrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MQp50DY3U4rNQmjaa5YI2UnvrUA9fNE5J_upSLE1D4c/edit#gid=0';
    return sheetRrl;
  }

// function to return the URL of the App Script
function getHtmlUrl()
  {
    var    execRrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbygbQGKjER0tdYbvVUHysu3iqCw9burRlM5EWqogpTpRac7mbNIdXCz6Uy2pFFp7jDE/exec"
    return execRrl; 
  }
```

interogatemenu.gs

```
function interogatemenu(tcu,tac,twa)
  {
    var spreadsheet    = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(getSheetUrl());
    var sheet          = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('permits');
    var int_uptally    = sheet.getRange("K4").getValue();
    var tx_useremail   = "demo@example.com"
    var tx_menuitem    = "example";
    var tx_permitlevel = "N/A";
    var tx_menutext    = "An Example";

    var menustring     = "<br>Menu Table Starting<br><table border = 1>";
    
    for(i=3;i<=int_uptally+2;i++)
    {
      tx_useremail     = sheet.getRange("A4").offset(i-3,0).getValue();
      tx_menuitem      = sheet.getRange("B4").offset(i-3,0).getValue();
      tx_permitlevel   = sheet.getRange("C4").offset(i-3,0).getValue();
      tx_menutext      = sheet.getRange("G4").offset(i-3,0).getValue();
      if(tx_useremail  = tcu)
      {
        if(tx_permitlevel == "R/O" || tx_permitlevel == "R/W")
        {
          menustring = menustring + "<tr>";
          menustring = menustring + "<td>";
          menustring = menustring + "<a href=";
          menustring = menustring + String.fromCharCode(34);
          menustring = menustring + twa;
          menustring = menustring + "?actioncode=";
          menustring = menustring + tx_menuitem;
          menustring = menustring + String.fromCharCode(34);
          menustring = menustring + ">";
          menustring = menustring + tx_menutext;
          menustring = menustring + "</a>";
          menustring = menustring + "</td>";
          menustring = menustring + "</tr>";
        }
      }
    }    
    menustring = menustring + "</table><br>Menu Table Complete<br>";

    return menustring;

  }
```

```
content.gs

// demo of content - first world content
function fwc()
  {
    localstring = "Hello and welcome to My first World<br><br>";
    return localstring;
  }

// demo of content - second world content
function swc()
  {
    localstring = "Hello and welcome to My second World<br><br>";
    return localstring;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems I have an answer from a different posting. andio asked about this and idfurw answered with information about iframe.

My code now includes the _top bit value for the target:-

```
      menustring = menustring + " target=";
      menustring = menustring + String.fromCharCode(34);
      menustring = menustring + "_top";
      menustring = menustring + String.fromCharCode(34);
```

Thanks all.